# run batch in wordpress docker container

Tags: php, wordpress, docker

I am trying to run batch in wordpress official container.
In container I want to run very simple batch like below:

./wordpress_batch.php

```
define('BASEPATH', '/path/to/wordpress');
require_once(BASEPATH . '/wp-load.php');

# batch program start
echo "batch test";
var_dump($wpdb);
```

But no output is shown.
This code work in wordpress in host machine.
What is wrong in docker container?
Any ideas to run this code?

Thanks.

./docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"
services:
    wordpress:
        build: containers/wordpress
        ports:
            - "9000:80"
        depends_on:
            - db
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "db:3306"
        env_file: .env
        volumes:
            - ./wordpress_batch:/var/batch/
    db:
        build: containers/db
        env_file: .env
        volumes:
            - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
    db-data:
        driver: local
```

./containers/db/Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:latest
```

./containers/wordpress/Dockerfile:

```
FROM wordpress:latest
```

The way I ran the code:

```
$ docker-compose run wordpress bash
# root@97658bd14387:/var/batch# php wordpress_batch.php
```

Comment: so you get a prompt inside your running container? I guess just launching a bash is not what you want.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Wild guess, does adding`<?php` at `wordpress_batch.php` beginning helps?